# Non-crashing web page display?

Tags: raspbian, web-browsers, crash

At my work, I was asked to set up a monitor to display a 6-page slideshow from [Zoho Reports](https://www.zoho.com/reports/). The setup I created works, but poorly, as the browser frequently crashes. I'm not in the office every day, so often when I come into the office, that monitor displays an unhelpful white page.

I was given a Raspberry Pi 1, and I used NOOBS to put Raspbian (Wheezy? I think) on it, along with a script to start the Midori browser in kiosk mode upon boot.

My suspicion is that Midori has a memory leak, and I'm pretty sure the "reports.zoho.com" site is *very* taxing on the browser client (which is rather daft for something whose use case is basically a passive terminal).

I also tried epiphany and chromium, but they both performed just as badly and/or were impossible to start up in kiosk mode.

**Question:** Is there a better (more stable) browser that can handle heavy client-side load? (Bonus (off-topic): Can I optimize the Zoho Reports to be less taxing? I've [asked](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/pre-render-zoho-reports-slide-show-for-a-low-performance-passive-monitor-display) this at Zoho's forum as well, and they've responded that "we are currently working on optimization and this will be resolved in the near future".)

**Edit:** I wonder how much work it would be to create a web scraper (that would run once daily) to get those pages (once they're rendered), and then display *those* instead of the zoho web site? I've no idea how to do that though...

Here's part of my crash log, where you can see just how often the browser needs to be restarted:

```
jgb@sales:~ $ cat /home/pi/sales-stats/midori-log.txt 
Mon Feb  1 12:47:15 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Mon Feb  1 12:48:36 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 0
Mon Feb  1 12:48:36 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Mon Feb  1 12:51:00 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 0
Mon Feb  1 12:51:00 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Mon Feb  1 12:52:01 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Mon Feb  1 17:07:03 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 134
Mon Feb  1 17:07:04 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Mon Feb  1 21:16:04 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 137
Mon Feb  1 21:16:04 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Tue Feb  2 01:24:56 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 139
Tue Feb  2 01:24:56 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Tue Feb  2 05:33:18 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 137
Tue Feb  2 05:33:18 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Tue Feb  2 09:41:02 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 139
Tue Feb  2 09:41:02 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Tue Feb  2 14:16:33 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 137
Tue Feb  2 14:16:34 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Tue Feb  2 18:29:03 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 137
Tue Feb  2 18:29:03 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Tue Feb  2 22:46:27 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 139
Tue Feb  2 22:46:27 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Wed Feb  3 02:53:10 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 139
Wed Feb  3 02:53:10 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Wed Feb  3 06:58:27 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 137
Wed Feb  3 06:58:27 CET 2016 Starting Midori ...
Wed Feb  3 11:03:49 CET 2016 Midori stopped with exit code 139
...
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser` apparently that midora is really buggy! I am not sure if epiphany works on Pi 1. If you could get Pi 2 and you know C# you could make and easy UAP!

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention but I did in fact try epiphany and chromium, but they both performed just as badly and/or were impossible to start up in kiosk mode.

Comment: Sadly, getting a HW upgrade is not an option, and I don't know C#.

Comment: Yikes... what is that website doing then. Scrapping the site is possible. I think there are some good Python tools for this. I only asked C# cause its pretty easy to scrape sites using a simple console app. Rolling your own dashboard in HTML based on some scrapped data sounds like the only good way, as you mentioned.